# Grassmann fields according to Peskin and Schroeder

Tags: quantum-field-theory, mathematical-physics, fermions, quantization, grassmann-numbers

On page 301 in [Peskin and Schroeder](http://physics.weber.edu/schroeder/qftbook.html), they claim that a Grassman field $\psi(x)$ may be decomposed as

$$\psi(x) = \sum_i c_i \phi_i(x),$$

where the $c_i$ are Grassmann numbers and the $\phi_i$ are "orthonormal basis functions".

I don't understand what is meant by "orthonormal basis function". Surely they would need to define some metric on the space of all fields to do this? I can't think of a natural one.

They claim that for the Dirac field the $\phi_i$ are a basis of four component spinors. Presumably they mean spinor fields here. I don't know of a natural basis for these fields.

Could someone clear up whether this is an error in the book or whether I'm missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even forgetting about the field for a second (meaning, forgetting about spatial-dependence and just focussing on one Grassmann number), a Grassmann number can be written as a linear combination of other Grassmann numbers, where the coefficients are complex numbers. For example P&S do that on the previous page (pg. 300) when they write a 'complex Grassmann number': $\theta = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(\theta_1 +i\theta_2)$. Those numbers, $\theta_1$ and $\theta_2$, are independent Grassmann numbers, and we've expressed $\theta$ as a combination of them.

So what we're saying with the field is that, at some point in space $x$, there's a Grassmann number defined, which is equal to the linear combination $\sum_i\psi_i\phi_i(x)$. We allow for the fact that the Grassmann number at, say, $x_1$ is different from $x_2$ by allowing that the coefficients in the linear combinations of those two Grassman numbers will be different ($\phi_i(x_1)$ versus $\phi_i(x_2)$).

The orthonormal basis functions $\phi_i(x)$ are the usual orthonormal basis functions you're used to (sines, cosines, spherical harmonics, etc.).

All they're saying is that we have maximal freedom to allow the Grassmann number at $x_1$ to be whatever we want it to be regardless of what the number at $x_2$ is. Just like we can create any real-valued function we want by choosing the real-valued coefficients correctly in, say, a Fourier sum, we can create any Grassmann-valued function we want by correctly choosing the Grassmann-valued coefficients ($\psi_i$) in the sum you asked about.

Comment: Many thanks: this is what I thought that they meant! So they mean work over the Hilbert space $L^2$ of square integrable functions, and use the metric given by $\int \phi^*\phi$. Then their "orthonormal basis" functions are just complex exponentials. Right?

Comment: So really their statement is kind of vacuous, because we only really ever think of $\psi$ as a Grassman valued Dirac spinor. They're making the point that if you wanted to you could rewrite it as a Fourier expansion with Grassman number coefficients. But we don't. Is this correct?

Comment: If I understand what you're asking: yes. I don't know much about the mathematical machinery behind Grassmann-valued fields (I'm sure there are many, many people here who can explain it well), but the way I think of something like $\psi(x)$ is that it's a field whose values are Grassmann numbers. The content of the sum you're asking about is that we can Fourier decompose $\psi(x)$, and the coefficients are Grassmann numbers. Like you say, I only ever see complex Fourier decompositions, but I suppose it's possible to do other decompositions.

Comment: And the reason why you have to do the whole shebang with orthonormal functions (rather than just with the $4$ fields making up a Dirac spinor) is because the Grassman variables at each spacetime point are independent - thinking about the path integral as a limiting operation. Would you agree? And thanks again - I've accepted your answer now!

Comment: @EdwardHughes : I deleted my answer because it was not clear... Yes, the idea is that each of the $4$ components of $\psi(x)$, for each $x$, is a (different) Grassman quantity, and we see this in path integrals.